# Seemingly random kernel panics for the last 3 months

Tags: snow-leopard

Sat Sep 14 09:38:58 2013
panic(cpu 0 caller 0x876eee8b): "Uncorrectable Fbd memory error detected. FERR_NF = 0x00000020 , NERR_NF == 0x02000021\n"@/SourceCache/AppleMCEDriver/AppleMCEDriver-119.4.0/AppleMCEDriver.cpp:947
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address (4 potential args on stack)
0x10bc58 : 0x21b837 (0x5dd7fc 0x10bc8c 0x223ce1 0x0) 
0x10bca8 : 0x876eee8b (0x876ef90c 0x20 0x2000021 0x8100a4) 
0x10bd18 : 0x876ef15d (0xf56b300 0xf56b300 0x2 0x820044) 
0x10bd98 : 0x7d7b0a50 (0xf56b300 0x0 0xf202980 0x0) 
0x10bdc8 : 0x7d7afd09 (0xee2a300 0x0 0x0 0x1c) 
0x10bde8 : 0x7d7beebc (0x1c 0x10be5c 0x8 0x7d7bc5f0) 
0x10be18 : 0x7d7bf0be (0xf1de91c 0x17 0xee2a63e 0x0) 
0x10be78 : 0x7d7c662e (0xecfdde8 0x10bec8 0x10bef8 0x0) 
0x10be98 : 0x56ac20 (0xecfdde8 0x0 0xecd5d80 0x0) 
0x10bee8 : 0x7d9be5bb (0xee2a380 0x0 0xee2a380 0x0) 
0x10bf18 : 0x7d7a3213 (0xf1d3500 0x0 0x0 0x49) 
0x10bf38 : 0x7d7ae911 (0x49 0x0 0x10bf78 0x0) 
0x10bf58 : 0x580d96 (0xed34b80 0x0 0xed34f80 0x49) 
0x10bf78 : 0x2ab432 (0x49 0x87e03d80 0x3d4 0x0) 
0x10bfd8 : 0x2a1c2e (0x87e03d80 0x2a2a00 0x0 0x2a2a5b) 
0x87e03e18 : 0x225bba (0x0 0xedc0c39c 0x649 0x84bf28) 
0x87e03e78 : 0x22698c (0x1 0xf2097a8 0xeccfc58 0x649) 
0x87e03ee8 : 0x2275b0 (0xf2097c4 0x0 0x295b6eed 0x64a) 
0x87e03f58 : 0x227631 (0x23014c 0x863ea0 0x0 0x2a45c9) 
0x87e03f78 : 0x2302e6 (0x23014c 0x863ea0 0x0 0x0) 
0x87e03fc8 : 0x2a179c (0x863ea0 0x0 0x10 0xf4e72e4) 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace (with dependencies):
         com.apple.driver.AppleMCEDriver(1.1.9)@0x876eb000->0x876f0fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.3.0)@0x7d4e4000
         com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC(1.4)@0x7d9bd000->0x7d9bffff
         com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform(1.3.6)@0x7d7a1000->0x7d7e3fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.3.0)@0x7d4e4000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.6.5)@0x7d6ea000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
10K549

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386
System model name: MacPro3,1 (Mac-F42C88C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 6914592368211
unloaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  2.0 (addr 0x871e1000, size 0x12288) - last unloaded 139509875363
loaded kexts:
com.rogueamoeba.InstantOnCore   6.0.3
com.rogueamoeba.InstantOn   6.0.3
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    2.1.0 - last loaded 49874422097
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.3d0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.7
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.20
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.57
com.apple.kext.ATIFramebuffer   6.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPenrynProfile    17
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.ATIRadeonX2000    6.3.6
com.apple.driver.AudioIPCDriver 1.1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.0.5f14
com.apple.driver.AppleIntel8254XEthernet    2.1.3b1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCEDriver 1.1.9
com.apple.driver.AirPortBrcm43224   428.42.4
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    4.7.0a1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.5.1
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  2.6.8
com.apple.driver.AppleRAID  4.0.6
com.apple.BootCache 31.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  1.6.4
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    4.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPIIXATA  2.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   4.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   4.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 142.6.0
com.apple.security.sandbox  1
com.apple.security.quarantine   0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   2.1.14
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   142.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileReadCounterAction  17
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileTimestampAction    10
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileThreadInfoAction   14
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileRegisterStateAction    10
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileKEventAction   10
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileCallstackAction    20
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   74.2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    2.4.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.3
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.0.5f14
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.2.1
com.apple.kext.ATI2600Controller    6.3.6
com.apple.kext.ATISupport   6.3.6
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  2.7.6f6
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.3fc2
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.3
com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily  41
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.0.5f14
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.0.5f14
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   320.1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  1.10
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.0d5
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 4.7.0a1
com.apple.driver.CSRUSBBluetoothHCIController   2.4.5f3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController 2.4.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   2.4.5f3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHIDKeyboard    141.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  4.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   141.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   4.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  3.9.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  2.6.8
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.6
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.6.1
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 402.1
com.apple.iokit.IOATAPIProtocolTransport    2.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   2.6.8
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.2.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 4.2.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.0.6
com.apple.iokit.IOATAFamily 2.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 4.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  6
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 289.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.6.3
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.3.6
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.3.0

Comment: I've been getting these KP events since may. Changed the RAM memory sticks four times. Purchased from OWC, they sent me matched pairs of 2GB RAM units. This is the latest report but, if anyone knows how to read these things, I've got plenty more...

Comment: @ankii The question here is years old, not sure Catalina related crashes apply here

Comment: @nohillside definitely a reading error, leave open and i’ll Remove the comment. I was focusing on com apple driver applesmc errors. Now that I read it again, that is also not applicable here

Answer (score 1):

It should be a problem associated with Instant On's kernel extensions. Try removing that and see if the problem goes away.

```
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver 2.0 (addr 0x871e1000, size 0x12288) - last unloaded 139509875363 loaded kexts: com.rogueamoeba.InstantOnCore 6.0.3
```